# Creating a Scale Between 0 and 1 Even when Higher numbers are passed in

Tags: ios, swift

I want to write an algorithm which allows me to rescale numbers to between 0 and 1. This means if I pass 25, 100, 500 then it should generate a new scale and represent those numbers on a scale of 0 to 1.

Here is what I have which is incorrect and does not make sense.

```
 height: item.height/item.height * 20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in the numbers in an array.

Loop through the numbers and find the max.

Map the array of integers to an array of Doubles, each one being the value from the source array, divided by the max.

Try to write that code. If you have trouble, update your question with your attempt and tell us what's going wrong.

### EDIT:

Your answer shows how to **print** your resulting scaled values, but you implied that you actually want to create a new array containing the scaled values. For that you could use a function like this:

```
func scaleArray(_ sourceArray: [Int]) -> [Double] {
  guard let max = sourceArray.max() else {
    return [Double]()
  }
  return sourceArray.map {
    return Double($0)/Double(max)
  }
}
```

### Edit #2:

Here is code that would let you test the above:

```
func scaleAndPrintArray(_ sourceArray: [Int]) {
  let scaledArray = scaleArray(sourceArray)
  for index in 0..<sourceArray.count {
    print(String(format: "%3d", sourceArray[index]), String(format: "%0.5f",scaledArray[index]))
  }
}

for arrayCount in 1...5 {
  let arraySize = Int(arc4random_uniform(15)) + 5
  var array = [Int]()
  for _ in 1..<arraySize {
    array.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(500)))
  }
  scaleAndPrintArray(array)
  if arrayCount < 5 {
    print("-----------")
  }
}
```

Comment: array of floats? The list is dynamic I can pass 100 items and also 10 items.

Comment: Ok, so take the input array, use it to create a new result array of floats. (Or Doubles, since that's the native floating point value for Swift)

Comment: Thanks found the solution using your advice. Thanks! Updated question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry but I don't know swift)

If you're wanting to create a linear scale, a linear equation is `y(x) = m*x + c`. You wish the output to range from `0` to `1` when the input ranges from the minimum value to the maximum (your question is ambiguous, maybe you may wish to lock `y(0)` to `0`).

```
y(0) = min
y(1) = max
```

therefore

```
c = min
m = max - min
```

and to find the value of any intervening value

```
y = m*x + c
```